# Joomla on RPi - Apache or Nginx?

Tags: joomla-3.x, apache, nginx

I have a RPi which will run a Joomla based website for allowing users to stream audio.

Comment: What does 'RPi' stand for?

Comment: @Mikan, I believe he meant "Raspberry Pi", so he won't be hosting it online but rather on a local "server" and stream to local network users.

Comment: It looks like you are simply looking to compare performance of Apache vs. Nginx. Some time ago I looked at PROs and CONs between the two. In my case Nginx wasn't an option because Joomla needed .htaccess for SEO-friendly URLs, which is only supported under Apache. In your case SEO may not be a concern, since it looks like you are hosting things locally.

Comment: @InsiderPro Thanx man... Raspberry Pi ?!? Hosting streaming server on that eeny meeny tiny thingy? Cool... :-)

Comment: @InsiderPro you can use SEF urls with nginx :) https://www.nginx.com/blog/converting-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: I think this post is off-topic as it's rather appears to be mainly a comparison between **Apache** and **Nginx**, irrespective of whether **Joomla** is run on a **Raspberry Pi**!; as such, answers are likely to be opinionated. It's not healthy for the community.

Comment: Your question is not about Joomla. Slowing down after many simultaneous streaming might be a case about your server resources and network capabilities.